# Excel - Count number of days from a range of dates (ignoring duplicates)

Tags: excel, date, count

Two columns: Start Date and End Date

Some rows contain duplicate dates (single dates AND dates that already exist within a range.

e.g.

```
ROW 1 = 17th January 2011 to 17th January 2011
ROW 2 = 16th January 2011 to 21st January 2011
ROW 3 = 24th January 2011 to 24th January 2011
ROW 4 = 24th January 2011 to 24th January 2011
```

I need to calculate the number of days within this range, but ignoring any duplicated dates. So in the above example, I need to ignore ROW 1 because it's a date within the range of ROW 2 - and I'd also need to ignore ROW 4 because its a duplicate of ROW 3.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect this can be achieved using formula but what have you tried so far?

Comment: First of all I would get rid of the duplicates...

Comment: Getting rid of duplicates ROW 3 and ROW 4 is simple enough, but what about getting it to recognise that the date range of ROW 1 lies within the date range of ROW 2?

Comment: Okay, just saw that you have two columns (I need to learn to read thoroughfully). With that you could simply use DATEVALUE to get the values of the earliest start date and the latest end date. Using MIN and MAX you can calculate the range. With that you could ignore the problem of the duplicates?

Comment: Sorry if my question sounds stupid.. when you say "calculate the number of days within this range" <-- are you referring to each individual row or just total from row1 to row4?